# Подгон картинок под строгий размер. Не ресайз.

Tags: gd, php

Подскажите какими средствами создаются картинки-миниатюры на страницах сайтов? Вопрос **не** по ресайзу. Все миниатюры имеют одинаковые параметры(150х100), а их оригиналы - совершенно разные размеры и даже пропорции. Я так понял, что оригинал сначала подгоняется под строгий размер - у него симметрично отсекаются стороны. Затем, это все уменьшается до копии-миниатюры. Какими средствами происходит автоматическая обрезка картинок-оригиналов?

Comment: как душа лежит, если это фотки то можно делать facedetect и по пропорциям золотого сечения рубить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Универсальный алгоритм:

1. Находим меньшую сторону (W|H)
2. Подгоняем ее под требования (если W, то 150, если H — 100), сохраняя пропорции делаем ресайз.
3. Обрезаем лишнее:

   - Если W>H (альбомная), то на этом этапе высота уже составляет 100 пикс. — обрезка по бокам таким образом, чтобы ширина составила 150 пикс.
   - Если H>W (портрет), то обрезаем низ так, чтобы высота составила 100 пикс.

Это можно объяснить так: если фотка альбомная, то основная информация скорее всего в центре; если фотка портретная, то главное — вверху (лицо стоящего человека).

Comment: @Bars, да, верно! Только величину требуемой обрезки делим пополам, чтобы обрезать с обеих сторон - тогда требуемое изображение будет отцентрировано и сохранит КАГБЭ сущность оригинала. Спасибо.

Comment: Это про пункт 3.1?

Только не упусти обработку квадратных изображений. И еще может вылезти такой косяк: если W всего на пиксель больше H, будет лажа. Ну и наоборот. Этот момент я усложненной проверкой обходил. Может, трезвые математики объяснят, как это можно предусмотреть проще :)